# parsing date is not working

Tags: jquery, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

My chart is working completely as expected, except that my parseDate function doesn't want to give me correct dates.

my csv date format:

```
 2014-03-22T07:00:18+0000,Pitty,1
 2014-03-18T18:50:51+0000,Ajay-Atul,1
```

i want to like date in following format:

```
 22-03-2014,Pitty,1
 18-03-2014,Ajay-Atul,1
```

i am trying following code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var chart = dc.pieChart("#test");
     var dataTable = dc.dataTable("#dc-table-graph");
     var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y").parse;

     d3.csv("{% static 'sampledata/time.csv' %}", function(error, experiments) {

      experiments.forEach(function(x) {
       x.Name = x.Name;
       x.Date = parseDate(x.Date);

      // x.Year=x.Date.getFullYear();

         x.Count = x.Count;



      });

      var ndx  = crossfilter(experiments),
      NameDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.Name;});
     // yearDim  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return +d.Year;});
     // year_total = yearDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.Count;});

      /*chart
        .width(200)
        .height(200)
        .dimension(yearDim)
        .group(year_total)
        .innerRadius(50);*/


      dataTable.width(800).height(800)
        .dimension(NameDimension)
        .group(function(d) { return "List of all Selected Businesses"
         })
        .size(100)
        .columns([
            function(d) { return d.Name; },

            function(d) { return +d.Date; },
            function(d) { return d.Count; }

        ]);




      dataTable.render();
      //chart.render();




    });

    </script>
```

Comment: What's the result you see?

Comment: zero value get the result of year column

Comment: Which date format do you actually have in your CSV? If it's the one you give an example of first, then your date parser is wrong.